# Solving a dual integral equation involving a zeroth-order Bessel function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, complex-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, improper-integrals

Consider the following dual integral equations

\begin{align}
  \int_0^\infty  q^3 f_0(q) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q &= g(r) \qquad\qquad\quad (0<r<1) , \\ 
  \int_0^\infty f_0(q) J_0 (qr) \, \mathrm{d} q &= 0 \,\quad\qquad\qquad\quad (r>1) \, ,
\end{align}
where
$$
g(r) = \frac{9}{4\pi} \frac{16h^6-72h^4 r^2 + 18h^2 r^4 +r^6}{(h^2+r^2)^{11/2}} \, . 
$$

We search a solution of the integral form
\begin{equation}
 f_0 (q) = \int_0^1 \lambda(t) \sin (qt) \, \mathrm{d} t \, , 
\label{integralWithHeaviside_sin}
\end{equation}
which clearly satisfies the integral equation for $r>1$ by making use of the relation
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty J_0 (qr) \sin(qt) \, \mathrm{d} q = \frac{H(t-r)}{(t^2-r^2)^{1/2}} \, ,  
\end{equation}
where $H(\cdot)$ denotes Heaviside function.

For $0<r<1$, it follows from three successive integration by parts that
    \begin{equation}\label{longEqBending}
   \begin{split}
    \int_0^\infty & J_0(qr) \, \mathrm{d} q \int_0^1 q^3 \lambda(t)\sin(qt) \, \mathrm{d} t
    \\
    &= \int_0^\infty J_0(qr) \, \mathrm{d} q \bigg( \left(\lambda''(1)-q^2 \lambda(1)\right) \cos(q) + q \lambda'(1) \sin(q) 
    -\lambda''(0) + q^2 \lambda(0) \\
&\qquad- \int_0^1 \lambda'''(t) \cos(qt) \, \mathrm{d} t \bigg) \, .
   \end{split}
 \end{equation}

For the integral on the right-hand side of the latter equation to be convergent, we require that $\lambda(0)=\lambda(1) =\lambda'(1)=0$.
Thus, the latter equation becomes
\begin{equation}\label{secondTermBending}
 \int_0^\infty J_0(qr) \, \mathrm{d} q \int_0^1 q^3 \lambda(t)\sin(qt)
 = -  \frac{\lambda''(0)}{r} - \int_0^r \frac{\lambda'''(t) \, \mathrm{d} t}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}}   \, ,
\end{equation}
after using identity
\begin{equation}
 \int_0^\infty J_0 (qr) \cos(qt) \, \mathrm{d} q = \frac{H(r-t)}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}} \, . \label{integralWithHeaviside_cos}
\end{equation}

Thus, the integral equation can be simplified as
\begin{equation}
    \frac{\lambda''(0)}{r} +  \int_0^r \frac{\lambda'''(t) \, \mathrm{d} t}{(r^2-t^2)^{1/2}} = -g(r) \, ,
\end{equation}

By multiplying both members of the latter equation by $r/(s^2-r^2)^{1/2}$ and integrating with respect to $r$ from 0 to $s$, the resulting equation reads
\begin{equation}
 \lambda''(s) = - \frac{24 h^3}{\pi^2 } \frac{s(3h^2 - 5s^2)}{(s^2+h^2)^5} \, .
\end{equation}

> > The latter equation can now be easily solved. 
> >     But the problem is that we have required that $\lambda(0)=\lambda(1)=0$ but also $\lambda'(1)=0$.
> >     As the final equation is a second order ODE, only 2 boundary conditions are in principal required. 
> >     I would be grateful if someone here could be of help and clarify how this could be explained.

Thank you!

Comment: The first thing I would do is to find the function $\lambda$ and then check if the conditions are satisfied (or better yet, that it makes your intermediate expression convergent, which is the whole reason you introduced them).

Comment: @YuriyS Apparently the expression of λ as calculated from the last math step with λ(0)=λ(1)=0 does not satisfy the condition λ′(1)=0. Accordingly, one intermediate step would in principle NOT lead to a convergence of the overall integral. Maybe the first derivative should just be by construction discontinuous? Any inputs are highly desirable